# Query to read data from URL

Tags: greenplum

I am using Greenplum Database.

Need to write query or may be function to read data from a URL.

Say a sharepoint URL is there, which contains some tabular data.
I need to write a query to fetch that Data from within the sql query or function.

I can get http_get, but its not helpful because the version is 8.2x.

I also tried python as pg language, it is also not working as it is listed as untrusted language. Hence looking for some alternative.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using web external tables:

https://gpdb.docs.pivotal.io/5170/admin_guide/external/g-creating-and-using-web-external-tables.html